# Swift 3.0 release method

Tags: swift3

I have a protocol in objc which looks like:

```
@protocol TestProtocol
- (void)releaseProtocol;
@end
```

Swift 3.0 automatically convert that to

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    func release()
}
```

But that creates a problem, because if I have a class which inherits from NSObject the compiler complains because the release() from protocol clashes with release() from NSObjectProtocol.

```
class TestClass: TestProtocol, NSObject 
{   
   func release() { #?@#.! }  // Compiler error
}
```

At this point, I cannot change the source protocol since it is in a SDK which I can't modify.

Is there a way to tell swift compiler to convert it to a different name, or to specify that the method fooRelease() corresponds to TestProtocol.release() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Objective-C declaration of that protocol must change. If you can't change it yourself, I'd suggest you issue a pull request to the author, asking them to employ a `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to allow Swift interoperability. You're probably not the only person using this SDK who will encounter this problem.

Thus, it should be declared something like:

```
@protocol TestProtocol
- (void)releaseProtocol NS_SWIFT_NAME(releaseProtocol());
@end
```

Comment: The real name isn't that bad, just made it simple for the question. In any case, The ObjC name will change in the future, actually I maintain the original SDK. But I wanted to know if there is a way to overcome this conversion without releasing a new version of the SDK.

Comment: We all hate distributing non-backward compatible changes to public API, but you might need to bite the bullet on this one. Besides, won't this only affect Swift 3 users? And since this doesn't work for Swift 3 users with `NSObject`-based classes, it comes down to how big your Swift 3 user-base who have implemented `release()` in their non-`NSObject`-based classes...